# Jquery Select Dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle the visibility of this. You'll notice there's a primary key number at the end of the id:

```
<div id="campaign-details-container-12">
```

And this is how I've tried to select it:

```
$(document).on("click",".show-details",function () {
    $(this).blur();
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var selector = "#campaign-details-container-"+id;
    alert(selector);

    $(selector).toggle();
    return false;
});
```

How can I get this to work? I could put a `data-id="12"` tag in the div instead and use a class, but how would I select by that?

Comment: show-details is a separate button

Comment: In the fiddle of @ArunPJohny, `show-details` is separated. What do you need?

Comment: Your initial version *should* work *as-is*. What does the HTML look like?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aeo6oo70/3/

Comment: @AmyNeville Maybe https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ can help.

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye I think there's something odd going on then - thanks guys for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just select it using the attribute starts with syntax:

```
$("[id^=campaign-details-container]");
```

No need to go do unnecessary things with classes and id variables...

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp

Comment: This would be a (much) slower way of doing it over adding a class to the elements and using that class as the selector.

Comment: Depends, if you add the class with js before using it as a selector then you're slower since adding a class is dom manipulation which is always slower.

Comment: Not if OP ads that in the HMTL template.